# How to create unsubscribe link using PHPMAILER

Tags: phpmailer, list-unsubscribe

Struggling to implement an unsubscribe header

- to single recipient it never creates the auto unsubscribe link (PASS DKIM, SPF & DMARC)
- to multiple emails, it adds up the link into each email and kills DKIM

Any clue ?
Thanks

```php
foreach ($result as $row) {
    try {
        $mail->addCustomHeader(
            "List-Unsubscribe=One-Click",
            "<mailto:unsubscribe@cineferte.fr?subject=Unsubscribe : $row['email']>, <https://cineferte.fr/abo.php?unsub=".$row['email'] . ">"
        );
            $mail->addAddress($row['email'], $row['nom']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Email invalide: ' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . '<br>';
        continue;
    }
    try {
        $mail->send();
        echo 'Email envoyé :' . htmlspecialchars($row['nom']) . '->' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . '<br>';
        mysqli_query(
            $db,
            "UPDATE `mailing` SET dat_sent = NOW() WHERE email = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string(
                $db,
                $row['email']
            ) . "'"
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Erreur (' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br>';
        $mail->getSMTPInstance()->reset();
    }
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why people set -1 vote.. the question is legit.. and the answer in this page works.. and it helped me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `addCustomHeader` correctly; you're trying to set multiple headers at once, which it doesn't support, and the format of the header contents is not correct either. Do this instead:

```php
        $mail->addCustomHeader(
            'List-Unsubscribe',
            "<mailto:unsubscribe@cineferte.fr?subject=Unsubscribe%20:%20{$row['email']}>,<https://cineferte.fr/abo.php?unsub=" . $row['email'] . ">"
        );
        $mail->addCustomHeader(
            'List-Unsubscribe-Post',
            'List-Unsubscribe=One-Click'
        );
```

Apart from that it looks like you're doing things right for sending to a list.

Comment: Many thanks for that, DKIM passes and single unsubscribe header sent.
However header only takes the first email of the SQL request to every single email sent

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. To fix that clear the headers each time around the loop, just as you do for addresses: `$mail->clearCustomHeaders();`

Comment: I am really sorry but after I implement $mail->clearCustomHeaders(); (either at the beginning or the end of the loop) there is no more unsubscribe header

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by inserting the addCustomHeader & clearCustomHeaders in a try/catch block within the foreach ($result as $row) { 
@synchro Thanks for the time spent